# Is there a way to use jQuery .on function with load event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not jquery/javascript expert and have been struggling to find an answer to this question.

I typically use jquery as follows because I use Ajax panels - so the binding persists through partial postbacks.

```
function setupBindings() {
    $("body").on("change", ".isvalidated", updateStateOnChange);
}
```

However, I need to carry out a function on load - something like the following code, and was wondering about the best way of achieving it in terms of my usual pattern.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('form').reset();
});
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `$(window).on("load", function(){});` ??? Or do you want the load to be fired when the partials are updated? You would need to find an event that the partials trigger since load does not fire for DOM updates.

Comment: Something different than `DOMReady`? (`$(function(){ /*code */ });`)

Comment: the [load event handler is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) (and [removed in later versions](https://blog.jquery.com/2015/07/13/jquery-3-0-and-jquery-compat-3-0-alpha-versions-released/)) and should no longer be being used.

Comment: not to mention that it doesn't work very well. Load as a concept is difficult to implement, which is why it was deprecated/removed

Comment: Need to do whatever it is in your ajax callback or use one of the global ajax event handlers

Comment: Did you need to separate `$('form').reset();` from delegation? Otherwise couldn't you chain it to `$("body").on(`?

Comment: I need to fire event each time the page is loaded or reloaded - because "body" is typically outside the update panel, the .on event works for both initial load and subsequent page loads. This is good as long as I'm using events like change, click, keyup, but I also need to do something each time the page is loaded (be it initial or postback). I can attach to the dom.ready and ajax pageLoad() event for partials but I thought there must be a cleaner way somehow.

Comment: the DOMReady event should do this? It fires everytime the page is loaded by the client (whether this is postback or load). Just use that? That said your not explaining yourself particularly well here. Your using updatepanels? Is this what your having trouble with?

Comment: FYI, I'd avoid update panels if you can, they are a nightmare and pretty much abandoned by everyone in favour of `$.ajax` these days.